# Ubuntu behaves differently(w.r.t. SIS VGA) when installed using ubootin (sharing windows XP) and when installed on a different partition

Tags: screen, display-resolution, vga

I am new to ubuntu and extremely sorry if this a repeat query. 
I tried ubuntu (18.04 LTS)on a laptop(Acer aspire 5000)- AMD turion 64 1.6 ghz, 2 GB ram, 40 GB HD (IDE), SiS VGA. There are **two aspects** to my query to seek help from the ubuntu community.

**1.** I tried running ubuntu using unetbootin by installing unetbootin in Win XP. Basically, its a live CD kind (i guess). I followed the steps properly and all went fine. I booted my PC and found out that it is wonderful.

**The screen resolution is great in this scenario.**

**At times - this way ubuntu misses to detect my keyboard. and hence I have to hard restart (by disconnecting the power which is bad).**

**2.** Finding it good i now went ahead to install ubuntu to the unused space on the hard drive of laptop by partitioning it. Installation went fine and then when i rebooted - 
  a. Key board issue was resolved. But,
  b. The Resolution is 640*480 and it remains so. I did some google and found out that the Sis VGA has an issue i.e. there are no Linux drivers provided by the Manufacturer of Sis VGA.

My Question -  Why does screen in the method 1 above comes up so crispy and can we do something to get that same when we go ahead with the 2nd Method.

Thanks
Ayt

Comment: SiS is a company, like Nvidia, AMD, or intel. They all make many video cards. The chipset is the important part (eg. intel isn't as useful as say the i915 chipset so providing that would be more useful than the brand of component.